# Selenium Webdriver, screenshot as numpy array (Python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

Is there a way to take a screenshot with selenium webdriver and convert in to a numpy array instead of saving it? I need to use it with openCV.

Note: I don't want to save the image and open it again

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm sure there is a more efficient way of doing this, but this is what worked for me:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from PIL import Image
import StringIO
import numpy as np

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('https://www.google.ca/?gws_rd=ssl')

data = browser.get_screenshot_as_png()

img = Image.open(StringIO.StringIO(data))

numpy_array = np.asarray(img)
```

Comment: Python 3: `import io; io.BytesIO(data)`