# How FAST give opencv browser screen(selenium)?

Tags: python, selenium, opencv, selenium-webdriver, screenshot

There is a game, where if you want to play you need to look all screen(all screen is a - canvas).  How can I give this canvas to opencv FAST(0.1 sec upd)? Now I simply make screenshots of screen with selenium(drive.save_screenshot("foo.png")) but this way is too slow(0.3-0.5 sec).

**Is there any way to save screenshots faster or other way to give opencv access to screen or smth else.** Maybe I need to save screenshot as bytes but not as file to upd canvas faster?

Also I found this https://python-mss.readthedocs.io/examples.html#part-of-the-screen but I didn't find how to use it with selenium. Python.

Photo of canvas:[image]

Comment: As I understand it, there's really nothing to integrate between mss and selenium. mss is a library that takes screenshots of your whole screen. So you'd run selenium in a non-headless mode so that the browser appears in the screenshot, then take a screenshot of the whole screen.

Comment: Thx, I read somewhere on the forum about this module that can be used with selenium but probably yes they mean use it just in a non-headless mode.

Comment: your question is on selenium so you should have tagged that.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium Webdriver, screenshot as numpy array (Python)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25584677/selenium-webdriver-screenshot-as-numpy-array-python)

Comment: Christoph Rackwitz, thx but I saw it and you can test for yourself that used time is the same